# What should the [transfer] tag be used for?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [transfer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transfer) tag currently has no wiki guidance and is generally used on questions for one of two purposes:

1. Questions about transfer functions, in which case the question is often tagged both [transfer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transfer) and [function](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/function) instead of the single, correct [transfer-function](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transfer-function).
2. Questions having to do with power or data transmission / "transfer".

The tag should eventually be replaced with [transfer-function](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transfer-function) for questions of type (1) but should we keep it for questions of type (2) or phase it out completely?

Comment: I looked through the questions and 90% of them that use transfer have the words transfer function somewhere in the question so they could easily be retagged as transfer function. The remaining 10% usually use something like data transfer or power transfer, unless somebody thinks otherwise I'll go ahead and merge transfer and transfer function

Comment: @VoltageSpike Merging the tags works for me.

Comment: @VoltageSpike I've finished retagging the questions that are about transfer functions. The [transfer] tag now just has 5 questions of type (2). I'm not sure whether it should just be removed for those questions or replaced with a more specific tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done, the tags have been merged